# Why is my whitespace text node not inserted?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

In order to prevent a thing that the browser is actually not supposed to do I am required to insert a `Text` node on the *left* side of another node. What I need is this resulting HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    "&#8203;"
    <div class="another-element-i-inserted"><!-- stuff --></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that what I am doing is actually only giving me

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <div class="another-element-i-inserted"><!-- stuff --></div>
</div>
```

Take a look how the debugger is lying to me:

[image]

The responsible code is:

```
Text textNode = Document.get().createTextNode("");
Element textNodeElement = textNode.cast();
textNodeElement.setInnerHTML("&#8203;");

this.pasteHtmlAtCaret(contenteditableDiv.getElement(), textNodeElement);        
this.pasteHtmlAtCaret(contenteditableDiv.getElement(), this.getElement());
```

where `pasteHtmlAtCaret()` is actually a `native` method aka JavaScript:

```
private native void pasteHtmlAtCaret(Element el, Element toInsert) /*-{
    var sel, range;
    if ($wnd.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = $wnd.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(toInsert);
        }
    }
}-*/;
```

Why isn't the text node inserted correctly? The problem I am having *without* that zero whitespace character is that if `another-element-i-inserted` is the first element in a row, placing the caret at the start will actually place the caret inside `another-element-i-inserted` which is problematic. I need the caret to *always" be placed in the `contenteditable`.

Any ideas/suggestions on this?

---

**Further information:**

Here you can see how the caret is `orange` instead of `black`. The reason is because the caret is actually inside the additional HTML content

[image]

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="contenteditable-textarea">
    <div style="display: initial;">
        <input type="text" class="mention-textbox notransition" style="color: orange; width: 35px;" readonly="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `innerHTML` on a text node, that's not going to work: this only creates an expando property on the node with no special meaning or behavior. You need to set the `data` property; and instead of an HTML character reference, just use that character in your source or use a Java escape  sequence.